# Finding if a class is key-value-compliant for a given key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

Is there a method to find out if a class is key-value-compliant for a given key?

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this better that the one from Grady Player? As you can see, DanSkeel believes the answer isn't completely reliable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can ask if it responds to the selector, or ask for the value for key

```
//will check for the getter
[anObj respondsToSelector:@selector(someKey)]

//will check in a way that doesn't throw an exception for a value
[andObj valueForKey:@"someKey"]

//keypath of a nested value
[anObj valueForKeypath:@"child.property"]
```

but if you are getting a message that something isn't KVC compliant that usually means you have set something up incorrectly, a binding with the wrong key or class for instance.

Comment: [anObj respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(somekey)] is correct

Comment: @rockey No it's not. Object can be key value coding-compliant for `somekey` but your method call will return `NO`.